# Unicode UTF-8 export csv from datagridview

Tags: c#, csv, unicode, utf-8, datagridview

I have written this code for exporting a `CSV` file from a `DataGridView` :

```
var dialog = new SaveFileDialog { Filter = @"Csv File|*.csv" };
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    return;
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var rowcount = dgvSum.Rows.Count;
var columncount = dgvSum.Columns.Count;
var headerCols = new List<string>();
for (var j = 0; j < columncount - 1; j++)
{
    headerCols.Add(dgvSum.Columns[j].HeaderText);
}
builder.AppendLine(string.Join(";", headerCols.ToArray()));
for (var i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{
    var cols = new List<string>();
    for (var j = 0; j < columncount - 1; j++)
    {
        cols.Add(dgvSum.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
    }
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", cols.ToArray()));
}
File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, builder.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(@"Csv file was created.");
```

But, I want to show Unicode characters in my created file. How can I convert to `UTF-8`?

Comment: Anybody Help me????

Comment: You're already writing it in UTF8.  It's not clear what your problem is, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: i user Persian characters. but it gave me an unclear file

Comment: I woudl check yout string before your write it to the file, I suspect it's wrong before you write it.

Comment: so now what can i do for fix it

Comment: I have no idea. You've not given nearly enough for anyone to work out what's wrong here.  As I said before, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Use overload `File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, builder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);` method.

Comment: @HoomanDaddy if that worked,  I suspect the issue is with the text editor you were using to view the file. The default is UTF8 without a 'Byte Order Mark'.  Other than the BOM, the output from that vs what you had previously is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()));
```

Usage:

**WriteAllBytes** method the second param means you can save file from string with specific encoding what you want including UTF-8.

You can use **ReadAllBytes** to compare with the other encoding  of string block if they are the same one.

```
string test = "Hello World!\u1255";
string fileLocation = "the file location you want to save";
File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation , Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test));

Assert.AreEqual(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test), file.ReadAllBytes());
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` already uses `UTF8` (see [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,3768ad284a63029f)), so this will give the same result.

Comment: i get error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string' WindowsFormsApplication2 C:\Users\kanoonadmin\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs 585 Active